# JQuery Update Box with More Information on Click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get display more information in a box when a user clicks a link but my JQuery code isn't working.

**HTML**

```
<div id="box"></div>
<a id="info" href="#">More Information</a>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#info').onclick(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#box').text('Here is your information.');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JQuery should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#info').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#box').text('Here is your information.');
  });
});
```

Notice that the function is `click` not `onclick`.

Answer (score 2):

You need `click` not `onclick`:

```
$('#info').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#box').text('Here is your information.');
});
```

or using `on`:

```
$('#info').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#box').text('Here is your information.');
});
```

as @prash suggestion, a better way to utilize `on()` here which is normally called as [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$('.parent').on('click','#info', function(){})
```

This will helps to make sure `click` event can be bind to your anchor even when your anchor has been dynamically added later on.

Comment: @prash What do you means?

Comment: your both options are same , or it should be $('.parent').on('click','#info', function(){})

Comment: @prash Maybe you misunderstanding me, I just use both case `on` and `click` since I'm not sure OP want which way so that's why I wrote `or` here

Answer (score 0):

### .click is a shortcut of .on('click')

use `.on` get better performance

```
$('#info').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#box').text('Here is your information.');
});
```